# Bash host DNS script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write my first Bash script that takes a user input like domain and runs the Linux command: `host -t ns [user input]`.
However my code does not work for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please enter a domain:" domain

if domain=grep -e /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
      do host -t ns $domain; dns
fi

echo $dns ;done
```

E: The error that I keep getting is:

> syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `then`, not `do` - `do` is for loops, not if statements.  Also, they way you are using the `domain` variable is wrong.  The right way to do this is:

```
if grep -qE '^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$' <<< "$domain"; then
  dns=$(host -t ns "$domain")
fi
```

- `grep -q` - doesn't produce output; just exits with 0 when there is a match and 1 otherwise (2 if wrong arguments are given)
- `-E` is for extended regex (ERE) that you are using
- the regex should be enclosed in single quotes, not `/.../`
- `<<<` is the here string
- `dns=$(...)` is the command substitution

Comment: Thank you mate, I only didn't meant what <<< means? does it mean that all this string from left is now = to the domain variable? and one more question, if I get multi output, how do I put each one in a different variable? lets assume I got 3 DNS address and I want each one to be in a different variable

Comment: Read up on 'Bash here string' to understand how it works.  For the second part, you need an array.  Take a look at the tag wiki - there are plenty of examples.